# How to type nested properties with keyof?

Tags: typescript

I want to type this method more strictly:

```
function deepCompare(key: string, name: string, value: any) {
    return sources[key][name] === value;
}
```

I've tried with `keyof` but not been able to get nested `name` to work:

```
type Sources = typeof sources;

function deepCompare<KSource extends keyof Sources, KName extends keyof Sources[KSource], T>(
    key: KSource,
    name: KName,
    value: Sources[KSource][KName],
 ) {
    return sources[key][name] === value;
 }
```

This call should return a type error: "3 is not a string"

`deepCompare("repo", "title", 3);`

But I'm getting `"title" is not assignable to type 'never'`

For reference, this is the target object:

```
const sources = {
    repo: {
        title: "hola",
        count: 3,
    },
    editing: {
        isDirty: false,
    },
};
```

Comment: `keyof` of union type is resolved to `never`

Comment: This should not be a union, I'm narrowing types in the nested properties: `keyof Sources[KSource]`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem in the [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).  Your code works as expected for me, except you don't need the generic parameter `T`.  Should this question be closed?

Comment: @Pablonete did you found a solution for this ?