# How to type prop for keyof nested object in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

The problem I've encountered is trying to enforce the correct typing on the props for a react component when requiring a nested objects keys.

The object I've been trying to pull data from follows this shape:

```js
interface Test {
    group1: {
        a: string
        b: boolean
        c: number
    }
    group2: {
        g: string
        h: number
        i: boolean
    }
}
```

The component is called like this:

```js
<MyComponent group="group1" key="a" />
```

I've tried typing the props of the component like this

```js
interface MyComponentProps {
  group: keyof Test
  key: keyof Test[MyComponentProps['group']]
```

but vscode intellisense tells me that the key is `never` instead of the keyof the group object. I've also tried a few generic type definitions but I haven't had any success with them. I assume the problem is because it's trying to reference the `MyComponentProps` group type which is returning a list of values instead of it's actual value. I'm not entirely sure how to go about fixing this.

I want the key prop to detect the correct possible values from the `Test` object based on the group prop passed to the component.

I found this post [How to type nested properties with keyof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695374/how-to-type-nested-properties-with-keyof) that seems to be trying to do basically the same thing but there's no answer.

Comment: Make it generic with respect to the group: https://tsplay.dev/NVYnnw

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `key` is a restricted prop name

Comment: @Konrad yeah, I realize that looking back at it. I just wanted to create an example that shows my issues without needing all the additional code surrounding it. It's not the actual prop name for my component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: as @Konrad noted, `key` is a restricted prop in React, because [it is used to identify list items](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key). Let's just rename it to `which` to keep things easy :-)

Now, let's take a look at `MyComponentProps`:

```js
interface MyComponentProps {
  group: keyof Test;
  which: keyof Test[MyComponentProps['group']];
}
```

What is `MyComponentProps['group']`? It's just `keyof Test`. So, the type is actually this symmetric-looking thing:

```js
interface MyComponentProps {
  group: keyof Test;
  which: keyof Test[keyof Test];
}
```

Why is `which` inferred as `never`? Let's look at `Test[keyof Test]`:

```js
{
    a: string;
    b: boolean;
    c: number;
} | {
    g: string;
    h: number;
    i: boolean;
}
```

Consider that `keyof (X | Y)` is not `(keyof X) | (keyof Y)`, it's `(keyof X) & (keyof Y)` – a value is only a key of the union if it's a key of each member of the union. Since there are no keys in common between `Test['group1']` and `Test['group2']`, `keyof Test[keyof Test]` is `never`.

So, that's why it doesn't work as is. To fix it, you need to provide a [generic parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) per @vr.'s comment:

```js
interface MyComponentProps<Group extends keyof Test> {
  group: Group;
  which: keyof Test[Group];
}

function MyComponent<Group extends keyof Test>(props: MyComponentProps<Group>)
{
  /* ... */
}
```

Intellisense is happy, Typescript is happy, React is happy.

```js
<MyComponent group="group1" which="a" />
<MyComponent group="group2" which="g" />
<MyComponent group="group0" which="a" />   /* error: group0 is not in keyof Test */
<MyComponent group="group1" which="g" />   /* error: g is not in "a" | "b" | "c" */
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I hadn't thought about how the TS would check for the inersections of the keyof of the two groups.